# Joining two dataframes on the basis of specific conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: First dataframe]I've added the images of both the dataframes here. Now I need to combine the two dataframes on the basis of two conditions:

Condition 1: The element in the 'arrivalTS' column in the first dataframe(flight_weather) and the element in the 'weatherTS' column element in the second dataframe(weatherdataatl) must be equal.

condition 2: The element in the 'DEST' column in the first dataframe(flight_weather) and the element in the 'place' column in the second dataframe(weatherdataatl) must be equal.

I tried the joins function but wasn't able to add both the conditions to it. it will be helpful if you could help me join them with the join/merge function. Thanks in advance.

[image: first [![second dataframe]dataframe][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrQOw.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrQOw.png)

Answer (score 2):

Follow mentioned link for your problems.

https://www.shanelynn.ie/merge-join-dataframes-python-pandas-index-1/